# .htaccess redirect from old location

Tags: .htaccess

Recently I changed the location of my css file and I want .htaccess to redirect all requests from old location to the new location. This is what I have:

```
RewriteRule css/^([^/]+)$ /newlocation/css/$1 [L]
```

for some reason this is not working. What should I do to get it to work. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^css/([^/]+)$ newlocation/css/$1 [L]
```

The other alternative, is to create a symbolic link from the root folder (linux os):

```
ln -s newlocation/css css
```

this will automatically redirect all request in your CSS to the new location of your CSS without using an .htaccess rule.